# If $G$ is a connected bipartite graph, then the edge ideal $I(G)$ is normally torsion free

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, graph-theory

I am studying the paper "[On the Ideal Theory of Graphs](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aron-Simis/publication/240478017_On_the_Ideal_Theory_of_Graphs/links/5ace7b05a6fdcc87840f0f23/On-the-Ideal-Theory-of-Graphs.pdf)" by Simis, Vasconcelos and Villarreal, Journal of Algebra 167, No. 2, 389-416 (1994), [MR1283294](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1283294), [Zbl 0816.13003](https://zbmath.org/0816.13003). I got stuck at theorem 5.9, that proves that **the edge ideal of a connected bipartite graph** is **normally torsion free**, page 408 of the paper.
I did not understand how they used induction hypothesis to conclude
$$
PR_P \in\operatorname{Ass}\left(\frac{R_P}{I_P}\right)
$$ in the 12th line of the proof.